# What does the Timezone in Settings -> General represent?

Tags: server, settings, current-user, timezone

Should it be set to the timezone of the server Craft is installed on, or the timezone of the current user, or something else?

I can find no documentation about these settings anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set it to whatever timezone the content authors will be in, so for example, when they say an entry’s post date is at 10 AM, Craft knows which timezone that should refer to.

Comment: Is it set per user then? What if there are content authors around the world?

Comment: It’s global; if the organization is spread across multiple timezones, they will just need to decide which timezone works best.